# this code i'm using in not a mobile responsive

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

This is what i am using bootstrap 3.3.1 this code is not  mobile friendly kindly look into. when i open in mobile all content gets small instead of convert into grids.please tell me what do to make it mobile responsive..
This is what i am using bootstrap 3.3.1 this code is not  mobile friendly kindly look into. when i open in mobile all content gets small instead of convert into grids.please tell me what do to make it mobile responsive..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
```

```
<!-- ====================================================
header section -->
<header class="top-header" >
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-5 header-logo">
                <br>
                <a href="http://mysite"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="" class="img-responsive logo"></a>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-7">
                <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
                  <div class="container-fluid nav-bar">
                    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                      </button>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">

                      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a class="menu active" href="http://www.mysite" >Home</a></li>

                        <li><a class="menu" href="#products">our products </a></li>

                        <li><a class="menu" href="#contact"> contact us</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </div><!-- /navbar-collapse -->
                  </div><!-- / .container-fluid -->
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header> <!-- end of header area -->




        <section class="slider" id="home">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">

                    <div id="carouselHacked" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">
                        <div class="header-backup"></div>
                        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                            <div class="item active">
                                <img src="img/-slider.png" alt="">
                                <div class="carousel-caption">
                                    <h1></h1>
                                    <p></p>
                                    <button>button</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="item">
                                <img src="img/-slider.png" alt="">
                                <div class="carousel-caption">
                                    <<h1></h1>
                                    <p></p>
                                    <button>button</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="item">
                                <img src="img/-slider.png" alt="">
                                <div class="carousel-caption">
                                    <<h1></h1>
                                    <p></p>
                                    <button>button</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="item">
                                <img src="img/-slider.png" alt="">
                                <div class="carousel-caption">
                                    <<h1></h1>
                                    <p></p>
                                    <button>button</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <!-- Controls -->
                        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carouselHacked" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                        </a>
                        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carouselHacked" role="button" data-slide="next">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                        </a>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </section>


        <br />
 <div class="container" id="products">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="img/women-care.jpg"  style="width: 140px; height: 140px;">
      <h2>Women Care</h2>
      <p>product description</p>
      <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
    </div><!-- /.col-md-4 -->
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="img/man-power.jpg"  style="width: 140px; height: 140px;">
      <h2>Man Power</h2>
      <p>product description</p>
      <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
    </div><!-- /.col-md-4 -->
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="img/"  style="width: 140px; height: 140px;">
      <h2>Product Name</h2>
      <p>product description</p>
      <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
    </div><!-- /.col-md-4 -->
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="img/"  style="width: 140px; height: 140px;">
      <h2>Product Name</h2>
      <p>product description</p>
      <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
    </div><!-- /.col-md-4 -->
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="img/"  style="width: 140px; height: 140px;">
      <h2>Product Name</h2>
      <p>product description</p>
      <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
    </div><!-- /.col-md-4 -->
    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="img/"  style="width: 140px; height: 140px;">
      <h2>Product Name</h2>
      <p>product description</p>
      <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
    </div><!-- /.col-md-4 -->
  </div>
  </div>
```

```
        <!-- map section -->
        <section class="api-map" id="contact">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 map" id="map"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section><!-- end of map section -->

        <!-- contact section starts here -->
        <section class="contact">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                        <div class="contact-caption clearfix">
                            <div class="contact-Product Name text-center">
                                <h2>contact us</h2>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-5 contact-info text-left">
                                <h3>contact information</h3>
                                <div class="info-detail">
                                    <ul><li><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i><span>Monday - Sunday:</span> 24X7</li></ul>
                                    <ul><li><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i><span>Address:</span></li></ul>

                                    <ul><li><i class="fa fa-phone"></i><span>Telephone:</span> </li></ul>

                                    <ul><li><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i><span>Email:</span> info@mysite</li></ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>


                            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-1 contact-form">
                                <h3>leave us a message</h3>

                                <form class="form">
                                    <input class="name" type="text" placeholder="Name">
                                    <input class="email" type="email" placeholder="Email">
                                    <input class="phone" type="text" placeholder="Phone No:">
                                    <textarea class="message" name="message" id="message" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                                    <input class="submit-btn" type="submit" value="SUBMIT">
                                </form>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section><!-- end of contact section -->


        <!-- footer starts here -->
        <footer class="footer clearfix">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-6 footer-para">
                        <p><i style="color:white;">&copy;</i> <a href="http://www.mysite"><i style="color:white;">mysite</i></a> All right reserved</p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-6 text-right">
                        <a href=""><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
                        <a href=""><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
                        <a href=""><i class="fa fa-skype"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>





<!-- script tags
============================================================= -->
<script src="js/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
<script src="js/gmaps.js"></script>
<script src="js/smoothscroll.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/custom.js"></script>
```